# Java input methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, input

I'm currently attempting to write a role-playing game with ***Eclipse*** (don't know how far I'll get, but who knows) and I'd like to prompt the user to answer with a sentence/phrase.

I'm learning very basic Java right now, but we know how to prompt the user to enter in either an integer or a double variable/number (er... mind is a little messed up) - similar to:

```
variable=input.nextInt();, or input.nextDouble();
```

Can anyone please list how to prompt the user for a phrase, and how to make the program recognize that certain phrase (and get results)? Thank you.

(One final note: I'm not the best programmer, so can you please list the simplest ways to do so?)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `input` is a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), so just use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to get a line of text. That will wait for the user to enter an arbitrary amount of text and press enter, then you'll get all the text they entered.

Answer (score 1):

Soln:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the phrase");
    String line;
    try {
    BufferedReader input =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
      if(!line.isEmpty()) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          System.out.println("token=" + st.nextToken());
        }
      }
    }
    input.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("DONE");
  }
```